# PrestaShop - Hook update quantity (FrontEnd)

Tags: prestashop, hook

I need to know if there is a hook when a user changes quantity (or size, for example) in product details page or in other site page (checkout process).

My purpose is to call an external API when this happened.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at **[actionCartUpdateQuantityBefore](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/actioncartupdatequantitybefore/)** ,
this is fired when front office cart is getting changed.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that'd be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are hooks in PrestaShop that you can use to trigger your custom code when a user updates the quantity or size of a product on the frontend.

For example, you can use the actionProductUpdate hook, which is triggered when a product is updated. You can then check if the quantity or size has been updated and call your external API accordingly.

Here's an example of how you can use this hook in your module:

```
public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
$productId = (int)$params['id_product'];
$quantity = (int)Tools::getValue('quantity');
$size = (string)Tools::getValue('size');

// Check if quantity or size has been updated
if ($quantity !== null || $size !== null) {
    // Call your external API here
    // ...
} }
```

This code will check if the quantity or size parameter is set in the request, and if so, it will call your external API.

You can also use other hooks like actionCartSave or actionCartUpdateQuantity, depending on your specific use case.

Make sure to test your code thoroughly before deploying it to a production environment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried your suggest but nothing happened when I click on quantity dropdown. I have installed my custom module and registred  "ActionProductUpdate" hook. 
 
 public function install()
    {

        if (Shop::isFeatureActive()) {
            Shop::setContext(Shop::CONTEXT_ALL);
        }

        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('ActionProductUpdate');
    } <br>
       public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
    { die('xxxxxx'); }